# Overriding the CSS applied by “a” tag

Tags: html, css

```
h1 a,
h2 a,
h3 a,
{
       color: #ccc !important;
}
```

this piece of code is not working,it doest override the color I set in A tag.
and I used important already.

how can I override the color in A tag??

```
header a 
{
        color:# 000;
}
```

this code is working though....

Comment: Any purpose of declaring `!important`?

Comment: Is your `a` actually inside a `h1`, `h2`, or `h3` tag?

Comment: Try not to use `!important`. It defeats the purpose of the (cascade) in cascading stylesheets.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a minor syntax error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:

```
h1 a,
h2 a,
h3 a
{
       color: #ccc !important;
}
```

You had an extra comma in your code, for your last line.

Comment: OMG,I didn't notice that